# Lubuntu + pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio, lubuntu

How can I install pulseaudio on lubuntu? When I try installing via sudo apt-get install, the package is not available.

I use kodibuntu (formerly xbmcbuntu) and want to get pulseaudio working to get sound in Grim Fandango Remastered to play properly.

Comment: So `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol` doesn't work? You may then try to use this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: Pavucontrol exists, and recommends pulseaudio, which  doesnt exist. I will try that ppa,thanks

Comment: That ppa only gives me "404 Not Found"

Comment: Pulseaudio is in main, so if it isn't available, there's something wrong with your sources. Which version?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS - KODIbuntu
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

I dont understand what is wrong?

Comment: Can you add to your question output from `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I have the same problem : pulseaudio package is referenced by others packages, but not available. Did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Kodibuntu blocks the pulseaudio packages from being installed by apt.

You can undo the block by removing/moving the following files:

- /etc/apt/preferences.d/libasound2-plugins.pref
- /etc/apt/preferences.d/libasound2-plugins.pref.bak

After this you can do another apt-get update and you should be able to install the packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can not install pulseaudio on Kodibuntu before you unlock the package.

To do so, remove /etc/apt/preferences.d/pulseaudio.pref by entering:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pulseaudio.pref
```

Alternatively you can also move the file to a backup location.

Afterwards you can install PulseAudio by entering:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```